# UrlFetchApp Post Req response inconsistent

Tags: google-apps-script

When I make a request via apps script, the response is inconsistent than when I make a request with a tool like postman or any other way of sending a post request, it seems specific to apps script.

Here is my request:

```
  var headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer #'},
  var payload = JSON.stringify({'_id':_id, "email": email}),
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'payload': payload,
    'headers': headers,
    'muteHttpExceptions':false
  }
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://...", options);
```

The response code is 201, it appears that the contentText returned in the response is correct except for one key piece of information, the email that was sent in the post payload should be in the response as well. After the post is sent, it triggers an email using the email sent in the payload.  This doesn't work with the apps script post request.

When I run this same exact request via postman or another tool, it works perfectly, the email is triggered right after the request is sent and works as intended.

Does anyone have any ideas why the "email" in the payload isn't working via apps script, but does via postman? Do I have an error in payload or way I'm using UrlFetchApp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change content type to:

```
'contentType': 'application/json',
```

The documentation shows an example with the object stringified, and they change the `contentType`

[Apps Script Documentation UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))